# Choosing combination of key pairs from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that contains the starting and ending coordinates of line segment. I want to compare all the possible combination of any two keys in the dictionary to check if the line segments have an intersection. How can I do that ?

```
v = {1:[(2,3),(10,12)],2:[(22,25),(14,42)],3:[(-8,10),(3,21)]}
```

The function for determining whether there is a collision is like this

```
def segment_intersect(line1, line2):
    i1 = [min(line1[0][0], line1[1][0]), max(line1[0][0], line1[1][0])]
    i2 = [min(line2[0][0], line2[1][0]), max(line2[0][0], line2[1][0])]
    ia = [max(i1[0], i2[0]), min(i1[1], i2[1])]
    if max(line1[0][0], line1[1][0]) < min(line2[0][0], line2[1][0]):
        return False
    m1 = (line1[1][1] - line1[0][1]) * 1. / (line1[1][0] - line1[0][0]) * 1.
    m2 = (line2[1][1] - line2[0][1]) * 1. / (line2[1][0] - line2[0][0]) * 1.
    if m1 == m2:
        return False
    b1 = line1[0][1] - m1 * line1[0][0]
    b2 = line2[0][1] - m2 * line2[0][0]
    x1 = (b2 - b1) / (m1 - m2)
    if (x1 < max(i1[0], i2[0])) or (x1 > min(i1[1], i2[1])):
        return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 2):

You may write

```
comb = ((v[x], v[y]) for x in v for y in v if x < y)
```

The `if x < y` part makes sure you only get `(1,2)` but not `(2,1)` which would be the same and not `(1,1)` which would not make sense.

You get an iterator with combinations and you can write:

```
for line1, line2 in comb:
    segment_intersect(line1, line2)
```

Note you should use a `list` rather than a `dict` if the keys are 1, 2, 3,...

Comment: Your answer is solid and a perfectly valid alternative. I think you can avoid duplication if instead of != you use < (in the comparison between x and y). Notice that sometimes the value of the answer does not depend on performance rather than pedagogical value. Your implementation is something a more advanced user wouldn't hesitate to use (besides iterable comprehension is currently very fashionable) :)

Comment: @armatita Good point. I edited my answer to use `<`. My answer might have a pedagogical interest but I think `itertools.combinations` is the way to go.

Comment: Agreed. It does seem the most adequate.

Answer (score 2):

You can just make nested loops for each of the pair elements. The following example does just this and tests the results with a plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
v = {1:[(2,3),(10,12)],2:[(22,25),(14,42)],3:[(-8,10),(3,21)],4:[(10,3),(2,12)]}
keys = list(v.keys())
print(keys)
for i in range(len(keys)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(keys)):
        print(keys[i],keys[j],segment_intersect(v[keys[i]], v[keys[j]]))
    plt.plot(*v[keys[i]],label=str(keys[i]))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

, result is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
1 2 False
1 3 False
1 4 True
2 3 False
2 4 False
3 4 False
```

, and:

[image: lines and interceptions]

Comment: Thanks for the reply @armatita. The graph explanation was really good.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the standard [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) function to generate combinations.

Eg,

```
from itertools import combinations

for k1, k2 in combinations(v, 2):
    print(k1, k2, segment_intersect(v[k1], v[k2]))
```

Using `itertools.combinations` is more efficient and more readable than using nested `for` loops, especially if you want combinations of length > 2.